# attaching a previous EBS Volume to a new EC2 Linux Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I ran into a problem the other day while cloning a github repo, and all of  a sudden my EC2 Instance (EC2 A) became completely unusable. My question is: how can I re-attach an EBS Volume from an EC2 Instance that I terminated to a new EC2 Instance that I just created?

Step-by-Step of the problem:

0) broke my first EC2 Instance (**EC2 A**).

1) created a snapshot of the EBS Volume (**EBS Volume A**) attached to **EC2 A**.

2) stopped **EC2 A**.

3) detached **EBS Volume A**.

4) terminated **EC2 A**.

Then...

5) created a brand new EC2 Instance (**EC2 B**) with a new EBS Volume automatically created (**EBS Volume B**), which is currently attached to **EC2 B**.

6) set it all up (apache, mysql, php, other plugins, etc...)

***7) Now I want to access my data from EBS Volume A. I do not care about anything in EBS Volume B. Please Advise...***

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: This question would be better asked on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can attach an existing EBS volume to an EC2 instance.  There are a number of ways to do this depending on your tools of preference.  I prefer the command line tools, so I tend to do something like:

```
ec2-attach-volume --instance-id i-XXXXXXXX /dev/sdh --device vol-VVVVVVVV
```

You could also do this in the AWS console:

> https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?#s=Volumes

Right click on the volume, then select [Attach Volume].  Select the instance and enter the device (e.g., /dev/sdh).

After you have attached the volume to the instance, you will want to ssh to the instance and mount the volume with a command like:

```
sudo mkdir -m000 /vol2
sudo mount /dev/xvdh /vol2
```

You can then access your old data and configuration under /vol2

Note: The EBS volume and the EC2 instance must be in the same region and in the same availability zone to make the attachment.